# ggplot: Prevent adding CI-region for one level of two

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with a factor with two levels, a continuous variable and a continuous outcome. I would like to show the two smoothed curves but only one curve should have a confidence region. Here is the dataset:

```
# Data             
xdf <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10,2)
                 , y = c(rpois(10,10),rpois(10,20))
                 , g = rep(c("A","B"), each=10)
                 )
```

and here is the plot

```
# Plot             
windows(width=12, height=20)             
ggplot(xdf, aes(x,y,linetype=g)) +
          geom_smooth(se=TRUE) +
          geom_point()
```

[image]

Any idea how to prevent one CI-region?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I see is overriding `data` argument like so:

```
ggplot(xdf, aes(x,y,linetype=g)) +
  geom_smooth(se = F) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(data = xdf[xdf$g == "A", ], se = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'm happy with this solution.